# UI hangs up for few seconds in iOS 6

Tags: iphone

My app works well most of the time. The problem arises when I go to iOS6 device settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner Status > Enable ON > Select the profile to 100 % Loss. When this profile is chosen, UI hangs up and becomes unresponsive for few seconds and then starts behaving normally.I am not able to find any reason behind this. Is there anyone who is coming across the same situation? If yes, then what measures were taken by you?

I think the following piece of code is creating trouble while trying to post to twitter using iOS 5 Accounts framework without using TweetSheet.The request is TWRequest here. The performRequest method is not guranteed to be called at any fixed particular thread as per Apple docs. How can I call this method on the main thread? Will it help?

```
 [request performRequestWithHandler:

     ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

         if(responseData)
         {
             //Do twitter stuff
         }
 }];
```

Comment: I'm not getting the same issue, are you sure you're not executing your network communication on the main thread?

Comment: Check if you **should not** calling a function in `main thread`.

Comment: are you downloading images on mainthread

Comment: Wrap the handler block in a GCD call: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ if (responseData) { // Do twitter stuff } });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're doing network requests synchronously, instead of asynchronously. Your UI doesn't seem slow when testing on a fast connection, but in poor network conditions, synchronous networking can cripple an app if it's done on the main thread. [Read this](http://blog.gruby.com/2011/01/29/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-networking-programming/).

Answer (score 1):

Since the UI is executed on the main thread, you definitely need to **avoid** calling any time-consuming method on such thread.
Network operations should be executed on a separate background thread.